# NgxAdmin freezes when load large Amount of nested data in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular11, nebular

using get by id API we fetch data for particular id in Angular 11

this is our form group

```js
export class PromotionsService extends HttpService<Promotion> {
  form: FormGroup;
  
  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    super('promotions', http);
    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      siteCodeId: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      promotionDealsTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      flightRegionPromotions: this.fb.array([], Validators.required),
    });
  }
  createFlightRegionPromotion(flightRegionPromotionOrder: number) {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      flightRegionId: ['', Validators.required],
      status: [true],
      order: [
        flightRegionPromotionOrder,
        [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)],
      ],
      promotionDeals: this.fb.array(
        [this.createPromotionDeal(1)],
        Validators.required,
      ),
    });
  }

  addFlightRegionPromotion(flightRegionPromotionOrder: number) {
    const flightRegionPromotions = this.form.get(
      'flightRegionPromotions',
    ) as FormArray;

    flightRegionPromotions.push(
      this.createFlightRegionPromotion(flightRegionPromotionOrder),
    );
  }
  removeFlightRegionPromotion(removeIndex: number) {
    const flightRegionPromotions = this.form.get(
      'flightRegionPromotions',
    ) as FormArray;
  flightRegionPromotions.removeAt(removeIndex);
  }

  createPromotionDeal(order: number) {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      flightRegionPromotionId: [''],
      status: [true],
      fromDestinationsListId: ['', Validators.required],
      toDestinationsListId: ['', Validators.required],
      airlineId: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      currency: ['', Validators.required],
      order: [order, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],
      image: this.fb.group({
        path: ['', Validators.required],
        type: [''],
        alt: [''],
      }),
    });
  }

  addPromotionDeal(
    flightRegionPromotionIndex: number,
    promotionDealOrder: number,
  ) {
    const flightRegionPromotions = this.form.get(
      'flightRegionPromotions',
    ) as FormArray;
    const promotionDeals = flightRegionPromotions.controls[
      flightRegionPromotionIndex
    ].get('promotionDeals') as FormArray;

    promotionDeals.push(this.createPromotionDeal(promotionDealOrder));
  }

  removePromotionDeal(
    flightRegionPromotionIndex: number,
    promotionDealIndex: number,
  ) {
    const flightRegionPromotions = (
      this.form.get('flightRegionPromotions') as FormArray
    ).controls[flightRegionPromotionIndex];

    const promotionDeals = flightRegionPromotions.get(
      'promotionDeals',
    ) as FormArray;
  
// **TYPESCRIPT FILE**

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-promotions-edit',
  templateUrl: './promotions-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./promotions-edit.component.scss'],
  // changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PromotionsEditComponent
  extends PromotionsCreateComponent
  implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit {
  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
  id: number;
  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
flightRegionData:FlightRegionPromotion[]=[];

  constructor(
    public siteCodesService: SiteCodesService,
    public toastrService: NbToastrService,
    public router: Router,
    public cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    public mediaUploadService: MediaUploadService,
    public generalService: GeneralService,
    public authService: AuthService,
    public promotionsService: PromotionsService,
    public flightRegionService: FlightRegionService,
    public hotelbedsService: HotelbedsService,
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    super(
      siteCodesService,
      toastrService,
      router,
      cdRef,
      mediaUploadService,
      generalService,
      authService,
      promotionsService,
      flightRegionService,
      hotelbedsService,
    );

    route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.id = params.id;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();
      }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // setInterval(() => {
    //   const expirationTime = localStorage.getItem(
    //     `promotions-expirationTime${this.id}`,
    //   );

    //   if (expirationTime != null) {
    //     const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    //     const expr = new Date(parseInt(expirationTime, 10)).getTime();
    //     const different = expr - currentTime;
    //     const remainMinutes = Math.floor(different / (60 * 1000));
    //     const remainSeconds = Math.floor((different % (60 * 1000)) / 1000);

    //     this.minutes.nativeElement.innerText = remainMinutes.toLocaleString(
    //       'en-GB',
    //       { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping: false },
    //     );
    //     this.seconds.nativeElement.innerText = remainSeconds.toLocaleString(
    //       'en-GB',
    //       { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping: false },
    //     );

    //     if (remainMinutes <= 0 && remainSeconds <= 0) {
    //       localStorage.removeItem(`promotions-expirationTime${this.id}`);
    //       if (this instanceof PromotionsEditComponent) {
    //         this.toastrService.show('Time Out', `Time Out`, {
    //           status: 'danger',
    //         });
  
    //       }
    //     }
    //   }
    // }, 1000);
  }

  loadData(){
    forkJoin([  this.generalService.getAllDestinationList(),
      this.siteCodesService.all(),
      this.flightRegionService.getAllFlightRegions(),
      this.generalService.getAllAirlines(),
      this.hotelbedsService.getAllCurrencyList(),
      this.promotionsService.find(this.id)
    ]).subscribe(([destinationList,sites,flightRegions,airlines,currencies,promotion])=>{
     this.originalDestinationList= destinationList;
     this.sites=sites;
     this.flightRegions=flightRegions;
     this.originalAirlines=airlines;
     this.currencies=currencies;
     this.getAllDestinationList();
     this.getAllSites();
     this.getAllAirlines();
     this.getHBCurrencyList();
     this.fetchPromotion(promotion);

     this.loading = false;
     
    },
    (error) => {
      this.loading = false
    })
  }

  fetchPromotion(promotion:Promotion) {
  
    if (promotion) {
      if (promotion.video == null)
        this.promotionForm.get('video.path').setValue('');

      (this.promotionForm.get('heroImages') as FormArray).clear();

      if (promotion.heroImages != null) {
        promotion.heroImages.map((image) => {
          (this.promotionForm.get('heroImages') as FormArray).push(
            this.fb.group({
              path: new FormControl(image.path),
              alt: new FormControl(image.alt),
              type: new FormControl(image.type),
            }),
          );
        });
      }

      const flightRegionPromotions = this.promotionForm.get(
        'flightRegionPromotions',
      ) as FormArray;
this.flightRegionData=promotion.flightRegionPromotions;
      flightRegionPromotions.clear();
  this.promotionForm.patchValue(promotion);
      this.loading = false;
    
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  onNextDataAddHandler(){
    this.promotionFormStepper.next();
    const stepIndex = this.promotionFormStepper.selectedIndex;
if (this.flightRegionData != null) {
  const flightRegionPromotions = this.promotionForm.get(
    'flightRegionPromotions',
  ) as FormArray;
        this.flightRegionData.forEach((region, regionIndex) => {
          let promotionDeals: FormGroup[] = [];
          if (region.promotionDeals != null) {
            promotionDeals = region.promotionDeals.map(
              (deal, dealIndex) => {
                return this.fb.group({
                  id: new FormControl(deal?.id),
                  flightRegionPromotionId: new FormControl(
                    deal?.flightRegionPromotionId,
                  ),
                  status: new FormControl(deal?.status),
                  fromDestinationsListId: new FormControl(
                    deal?.fromDestinationsListId,
                    Validators.required,
                  ),
                  toDestinationsListId: new FormControl(
                    deal?.toDestinationsListId,
                    Validators.required,
                  ),
                  airlineId: new FormControl(
                    deal?.airlineId,
                    Validators.required,
                  ),
                  price: new FormControl(deal?.price, Validators.required),
                  currency: new FormControl(
                    deal?.currency,
                    Validators.required,
                  ),
                  order: new FormControl(deal?.order, [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.min(1),
                  ]),
                  image: new FormGroup({
                    path: new FormControl(
                      deal?.image?.path,
                      Validators.required,
                    ),
                    type: new FormControl(deal?.image?.type),
                    alt: new FormControl(deal?.image?.alt),
                  }),
                });
              },
            );
          }
          flightRegionPromotions.push(
            this.fb.group({
              id: [region.id],
              flightRegionId: [region.flightRegionId],
              status: [region.status],
              order: [
                region.order,
                [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)],
              ],
              promotionDeals: this.fb.array(promotionDeals),
            }),
          );
        });
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<nb-card [ngClass]="{ 'edit-promotion-card': loading === true }">
  <nb-card-header class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span> Edit Promotion : {{ id }} </span>
  </nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body *ngIf="loading" class="edit-nb-card-body">
    <ngx-loader> </ngx-loader
  ></nb-card-body>
  <nb-card-body>
    <form [formGroup]="promotionForm">
      <nb-stepper #promotionFormStepper orientation="horizontal">
        <!--details-->
        <nb-step [label]="details" completed>
          <ng-template #details>Details</ng-template>
          <nb-card>
            <nb-card-body>
              <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="descriptionTitle" class="label"
                      >Description Title</label
                    >
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      nbInput
                      fullWidth
                      id="descriptionTitle"
                      placeholder=""
                      formControlName="descriptionTitle"
                      class="is-invalid"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
             
                </div>
              </div>
            </nb-card-body>
          </nb-card>
          <!-- nbStepperNext -->
          <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-end w-100">
            <button nbButton  (click)="onNextDataAddHandler()" class="next-btn">next</button>
          </div>
        </nb-step>
        <nb-step [label]="promotiondeals" completed>
          <ng-template #promotiondeals>Promotion Deals</ng-template>
          <nb-card  formArrayName="flightRegionPromotions"
            *ngFor="
              let region of flightRegionPromotionsControls;
              let regionIndex = index
            "
          >
            <!-- formGroupName regionIndex" START-->
            <div [formGroupName]="regionIndex">
              <nb-card-header
                class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center section-nb-header"
              >
                <span> Region {{ regionIndex + 1 }}</span>
              </nb-card-header>
              <nb-card-body>
                <div class="row pl-3 pr-3 pb-3">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label [for]="'flightRegionId' + regionIndex" class="label"
                      >Flight Region</label
                    >
                    <nb-select
                      fullWidth
                      placeholder="Flight Region"
                      formControlName="flightRegionId"
                      [id]="'flightRegionId' + regionIndex"
                    >
                      <nb-option
                        *ngFor="let option of flightRegions"
                        (selectionChange)="onFlightRegionChangeHandler()"
                        (click)="
                          onFlightRegionAvailableChangeClickHandler(
                            option.id,
                            regionIndex
                          )
                        "
                        [value]="option.id"
                        [id]="'flightRegionId' + regionIndex"
                      >
                        {{ option.name }}
                      </nb-option>
                    </nb-select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- promotionDeals START-->
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <nb-card  formArrayName="promotionDeals"
                    *ngFor="
                      let deal of promotionDeals(regionIndex).controls;
                      let promotionDealIndex = index
                    "
                  >
                    <div [formGroupName]="promotionDealIndex">
                      <nb-card-header
                        class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
                      >
                        <span
                          >Region {{ regionIndex + 1 }} | Deal
                          {{ promotionDealIndex + 1 }}</span
                        >
                      </nb-card-header>
                      <nb-card-body>
                        <div class="row p-2">
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label
                                class="label"
                                [for]="
                                  'flight-region' +
                                  regionIndex +
                                  'promotion-deal-fromDestinationsListId' +
                                  promotionDealIndex
                                "
                                >From</label
                              >

                              <nb-select
                              fullWidth
                              placeholder="From"
                              formControlName="fromDestinationsListId"
                              [id]="
                              'flight-region' +
                              regionIndex +
                              'promotion-deal-fromDestinationsListId' +
                              promotionDealIndex
                            "
                            >
                                 <nb-option
                                *ngFor="let option of originalDestinationList"
                                
                                (click)="
                                promotionDealDestinationListFromClickHandler(
                                  $event,
                                  regionIndex,
                                  promotionDealIndex
                                )
                              "
                                [value]="option.id"
                                [id]="
                                'flight-region' +
                                regionIndex +
                                'promotion-deal-fromDestinationsListId' +
                                promotionDealIndex
                              "
                              >
                                
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                  <div>
                                    {{ option.airportName }} -({{
                                      option.airportCode
                                    }})
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                    {{ option.cityName }}
                                    -{{ option.countryName }}
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </nb-option>
                            </nb-select>
                        
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label
                                class="label"
                                [for]="
                                  'flight-region' +
                                  regionIndex +
                                  'promotion-deal-toDestinationsListId' +
                                  promotionDealIndex
                                "
                                >To</label
                              >
                              <nb-select
                              fullWidth
                              placeholder="From"
                              formControlName="toDestinationsListId"
                              [id]="
                              'flight-region' +
                              regionIndex +
                              'promotion-deal-toDestinationsListId' +
                              promotionDealIndex
                            "
                            >
                              <nb-option
                                *ngFor="let option of originalDestinationList"
                                
                                (click)="
                                promotionDealDestinationListToClickHandler(
                                  $event,
                                  regionIndex,
                                  promotionDealIndex
                                )
                              "
                                [value]="option.id"
                                [id]="
                                'flight-region' +
                                regionIndex +
                                'promotion-deal-toDestinationsListId' +
                                promotionDealIndex
                              "
                              >
                                
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                  <div>
                                    {{ option.airportName }} -({{
                                      option.airportCode
                                    }})
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                    {{ option.cityName }}
                                    -{{ option.countryName }}
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </nb-option>
                              </nb-select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                      </nb-card-body>
                      <nb-card-footer>
                        <div
                          class="row no-gutters my-3 justify-content-end w-100"
                        >
                          <div
                            class="pr-2"
                          >
                            <button
                              nbButton
                              class="new-btn"
                              status="primary"
                              (click)="AddPromotionDealHandler(regionIndex)"
                              size="small"
                            >
                              Add New Deal
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div *ngIf="promotionDeals(regionIndex).length > 1">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </nb-card-footer>
                    </div>
                  </nb-card>
                  <!-- formArrayName promotionDeals End -->
                </div>
              </nb-card-body>
            </div>
          </nb-card>

          <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-end w-100">
            <button nbButton nbStepperPrevious class="mr-2 prev-btn">
              prev
            </button>
          </div>
        </nb-step>
      </nb-stepper>
    </form>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

when we fetch data flight Region has 6 array and each region has 8 promotion deals
when we bind this using **fetchPromotion**(promotion)
Application is stacked and cannot do any thing

After i change to add data during when click **NEXT** button
it also take some time and when add new promotion deal  it takes time to add new Deal view to user

when i check with js profiler 4 drop downs at promotion deals array is caused

Are there any ways to sort out this?